# Как извлечь файл из zip по адресу без копирования директорий из zip

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, zip

Предположим, у меня есть zip файл *imgs.zip*, следующего вида:

```
/cats/1.png
/cats/2.png
/dogs/1.png
/dogs/2.png
...
```

Я попробовал извлечь так:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(TexturePath) as myzip: 
    ZipList = myzip.namelist()
    num = 0
    for file in ZipList:
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
        if file_extension in ['.png']: # извлекаем только .png
            myzip.extract(file, os.path.join(temp, str(num)+file_extension))
            num += 1
    myzip.close()
```

НО! При таком коде *myzip.extract* копирует не только сам файл, но и директории
Т.е. путь, где искать извлеченный файл будет: `/путь_извлечения/cats_или_dogs/изображение`
А нужно `/путь_извлечения/изображение`
Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать `infolist()`, вместо `namelist()`, то появляется возможность изменять атрибут `filename` у файла в архиве.

***Пример:***

```py
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile


with ZipFile('imgs.zip') as archive:
    num = 0
    for member in archive.infolist():
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(member.filename)

        if extension in ['.png']:
            member.filename = f'{num}{extension}'
            archive.extract(member, './путь_извлечения/')
            num += 1
```

При необходимости повторно обращаться к элементам архива, можно делать так:

```py
backup = member.filename
member.filename = f'{num}{extension}'
archive.extract(member, './путь_извлечения/')
member.filename = backup
```